# Node is loosing peers, it there a way to force lock a connection

Tags: nodes, bootnode

One of our nodes is struggling to keep its peers and often gets disconnected from the other nodes. This node is in our set of bootnodes.

Is there a way to flag the peers connection between (boot)nodes so they will try harder to stay connected?

Comment: is reserved-nodes what I'm looking for?

Comment: Seems like there is an underlying issue as to why the node is loosing its peers, I would troubleshoot that.